# SQL WHERE clause with multiple XML attributes

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have table in database with XML column. Now I need to select some rows by two attributes from XML.
So far I've come up with this:

```
SELECT o.Id 
FROM Objects o 
WHERE o.SerializedObject.value('(/object/param[@id="111"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(8)') = '-1'
  AND o.SerializedObject.value('(/object/param[@id="222"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(8)') = '8'
```

EDIT:

XML is like:

```
<object>
   <param id="1" value="111"/>
   <param id="2" value="222"/>
   ...
   <param id="200" value="4545"/>
<object>
```

Each object has ~2k params.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do that with single XML query.

Comment: Why dont you parse your XML into a temp table first. Applying where or other manipulations would be easier

Comment: Each XML has ~2k nodes in it, so I thought it wouldn't be efficient to select values to temp table

Comment: Might there be repeating `<param>` with `@id="111"` within one XML? If I get this correctly, you are checking the existance of certain combinations... The temp table would produce quite some overhead I suppose...

Comment: With 2K nodes, you're going to see rather poor performance from queries like these, temp table or not. If this isn't a one-off query, you can consider looking at XML indexes, or pre-shredding some nodes in dedicated columns. Needless to say, a fully relational structure (by expanding the whole thing into a table) is always going to perform better.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your XML (you did not show an example, but I assume this is kind of EAV).

You can try using XML's method `.exist()`:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Comment VARCHAR(100),SerializedObject XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('just one of them','<object><param id="111" value="-1"/></object>')
,('both, but wrong values','<object><param id="111" value="-1"/><param id="222" value="-1"/></object>')
,('both, should fit','<object><param id="111" value="-1"/><param id="222" value="8"/></object>')

SELECT o.Id,o.Comment,o.SerializedObject
FROM @mockup o 
WHERE o.SerializedObject.exist('/object[param[@id="111" and @value="-1"] and param[@id="222" and @value="8"]]')=1;
```

`.exist()` is the fastest here, because it does not return any value. It will just return `1` on the first occurance found. This is especially fast, when there are many occurances of a `<param id="111" value="???">` Otherwise you'd have to shred the whole lot and place the filter on the whole resultset.

And - of course! - the necessary hint: As told in a comment by Jeroen Mostert dealing with bigger XMLs might turn out as a bottle neck. If you need this more often, you might think about a *relational* design instead of big XMLs...